# Difference between containing a cycle of length 3 and containing an element having a cycle of length 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The whole question is to prove that if $n \geq 5$ and $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $A_n$ then $N$ = $A_n$.  the problem is broken down into three parts.  (a) is showing that $N$ contains an element having a cycle of length $\geq 3$ and (b) is showing that N contains a cycle of length 3.  What is the difference?  I have been given hints to prove both, but I don't know how to use them.  For a, I was told to use the description of conjugate permutations given in the proposition "If $f$ is an irreducible polynomial over a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $deg(f) =n \geq 2$ is prime and $f$ has precisely $n-2$ real roots.  Then $Gal_F(f)$ is isomorphic to the full permutation group $S_n$.  For b I was told to consider $f=(123...)(..)..$ take a cycle $g=(12x)$ and compute the commutator $f^{-1}gfg^{-1}$.  Any assistance is appreciated.  I mostly don't really see what the difference between a and b is so if someone could explain that, that would be great.  I've seen elsewhere that $A_n$ is generated by 3 cycles and then $A_n = N$ as a result, but I haven't been able to figure out or find anything related to (a)

Comment: Your first sentence is incomplete.

Comment: @DerekHolt Fixed. Thanks.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

(b) means that $N$ contains an element like $(3~4~5)$.  One cycle of length 3 (and all other cycles of length 1).

(a) means that $N$ contains an element like $(1~2~3)(4~5~6)$ or $(1~2)(3~4~5)$.  At least one cycle of length 3, and the other disjoint cycles can be anything.

Comment: Thanks.  So for b, I think the answer is that since $A_n$ contains all even permutations then $(a b c) = (a b)(b c)$ is in $A_n$.  I still don't get how to show part (a) though.  Could you give me a hint?